# Service that takes an e-mail or text message and makes a voice call converting the text to speech?

Tags: text-to-speech

I am writing a server monitoring application that I'd like to alert me with a voice call if the server doesn't respond correctly when tested.

The application currently sends a text message to my mobile phone, but that hasn't worked as well as I would like, because I don't always have my mobile phone with me, or I don't hear it.

I'm wondering if there is a service to whom I could send an e-mail or text message and have it place a voice call to one or more phone numbers and read the message?

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: Are you planning on developing such a service? If so, great! If not, then this doesn't sound like a *programming* problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Twilio

http://www.twilio.com/

They have a nice simple api that can do the voice calls. You would need to write some simple code to read the email and then feed it into their api.

Hope this helps.

Bob